# How To Handle Twilio Voice FAlLLBACK URL and STATUS CALLBACKURL C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twilio

I want to handle twilio status callback and fallback url web-hooks while network error of some connection interruption or call disconnected or not answered.

What I get is to set a Web-hook and handle voice xml messages like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
    <Say>
      An application error has occured.  
      Please call back later
    </Say>
</Response>
```

this is the link : [Twilio Voice Fallback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/security/availability-reliability#fallback-urls)

But I'm not able to handle these all web-hooks. it throws me error says "An application error has occured. Please call back later"

Comment: Isn't the error message you are getting the one you told it to give?

Comment: This message is the default message from the twilio fallback response.
I've created my own fallback url but that is never called.

Comment: How are you simulating the failure of the primary twiml endpoint?

Comment: I've created a web-hook for fallback url with custom TwiML response  (i.e. All the lines of this root are busy at the moment, Please try after some time!). and Setup this url yo TwiML applicatio Voice Fallback Url.

Comment: Can you explain how you've setup your number? Are you using a TwiML application or have you set URLs for the primary and fallback URL for the number itself?

Comment: I've TwiML Application.